# Metric spaces why does $d_1(f, g)=\int_{0}^{1}|f-g|=0$ imply $f=g$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, metric-spaces

For f and g real valued continuous functions on [0,1] let $d_1(f, g)=\int_{0}^{1}|f-g|$

Why does $d_1(f,g)=0$ imply $f=g$?

I have been trying to work this out I think it is because the only function that can be integrated to $0$ is $0$? Is there a better way of phrasing this or is there a better reason why this is the case?

Comment: If the integral of a non-negative function is zero, then the function must be zero (almost everywhere).

Comment: The only **continuous non-negative** function that integates to $0$ is $0$

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen I don't believe you need continuity, just nonzero almost everywhere.  Is there a counterexample?

Comment: @Matt: OP might not know measure theory

Comment: @Matt Although the function being zero almost everywhere is not enough to guarantee Riemann integrability.

Comment: @parsiad My bad, I didn't notice the continuous assumption.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suppose that there is some point where $f(x)\ne g(x)$, so $f<g$ or $g<f$. In any event 
$$
|f(x)-g(x)|\geq \epsilon >0
$$
But by continuity of $f-g$ and the absolute value function, there is some delta ball for which $|f(x')-g(x')|\geq \epsilon >0$ for any $x'\in B_{\delta}(x)$ (I assumed we weren't at one of the endpoints to take a symmetric neighborhood, but the proof is no different).

Then,
$$
\int_0^1|f(t)-g(t)|\mathrm dt=\int_0^{x-\delta}|f(t)-g(t)|\mathrm dt+\int_{x-\delta}^{x+\delta}|f(t)-g(t)|\mathrm dt+\int_{x+\delta}^{1}|f(t)-g(t)|\mathrm dt\geq \inf_{t\in (x-\delta,x+\delta)}|f(t)-g(t)|*2\delta\geq2\epsilon\delta>0
$$

Note that continuity is crucial here; without it $f=g$ almost everywhere, since that's all the integral sees.

Comment: Since $(x - \delta, x + \delta)$ is not compact, the minimum may not exist. Moreover, the infimum might be 0. What you want to do is ensure that $|f(x) - g(x)| \ge \varepsilon > 0$ for some appropriate choice of $\varepsilon$. The easiest choice here is $1/2 |f(x') - g(x')$. Or, if you don't want to do that, take any compact interval contained in $(x - \delta, x + \delta)$ with positive volume.

Answer (score 5):

**Hint**: Let $h=|f-g|$. Suppose $d_1(f,g)=0$ and $h(x)\neq 0$ at some point $x$ (and hence $h(x)>0$). Since $h$ is continuous, we can find a (non-singleton) interval $I\subset [0,1]$ containing $x$ such that $h \geq h(x)/2$ on $I$. Now, try to arrive at a contradiction by reasoning about the quantity $$d_1(f,g)=\int_0^1 |f-g|=\int_0^1 h\geq \int_I h.$$