# Proving that $d(f,g) = 0 \implies f = g.$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, metric-spaces

I am trying to prove the following question:

Let $X = \{ f: f:[0,1] \to \mathbb R, f \text{ is continuous} \}$.

Prove that $d(f,g) = \int_0^1|f(t) - g(t)|dt$ is a metric on $X.$

Here is a solution:

> [image]

I see that this solution is not correct and I am suggesting that it should be like this, assume that  $d(f,g) = \int_0^1|f(t) - g(t)|dt =0 ,$  now since the integration of a nonnegative function equals zero iff the nonnegative function is zero, that is $|f(t) - g(t)| = 0$ i.e., $f(t) - g(t) = 0$ that is $f(t) = g(t).$

Is my solution (the second solution) correct or I am missing something and the first solution is the correct one?

Comment: *“I see that this solution is not correct”* – why?

Comment: *“since the integration of a nonnegative function equals zero iff the nonnegative function is zero”* – that is exactly what the quoted solution proves (for continuous functions).

Comment: @MartinR but is not this a thm already known?

Comment: It is unclear to me what you are asking. The quoted solution proves that for continuous functions, $\int_0^1|f(t) - g(t)|dt =0$ if and only if $f(t) = g(t)$ everywhere on the interval. I cannot see an error in that proof. – If you already “know” that the integration of a nonnegative function equals zero iff the nonnegative function is zero, even better for you. That does not make the given proof wrong.

Comment: There are usually several correct answers to a problem. Yours is not precise enough (depending on the context, there might exist nonzero nonnegative functions that have integral $0$). Moreover, it is sometimes not clear what parts of the course one is allowed to use, in an exercise. But reproving something proved in the course is never a mistake.

Comment: @Plop I should add continuous sorry

Comment: The title focuses attention on one of the conditions for $d(f,g)$ to be a metric (on the function space you call $X$).  But the body of the Question does not seem to have that focus, which is perhaps an oversight on your part.  The fact that functions in $X$ are continuous is crucial to proving what you asked in the *title*.  Of course there is more to being a metric, e.g. showing the triangle inequality.  I'm not sure if you are trying to tackle all parts of the definition of *metric*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your answer already assumes what you are asked to prove and the other answer is correct.

$\int |f-g|=0$ implies that $f=g$ almost everywhere. To show that $f(x)=g(x)$ for **every** $x$ you need continuity and the fact that the complement of  set of measure $0$ is dense.

Note that if $f(x)=1$ for $x=0$  and $0$ for $x$ all other $x$ then $\int |f(x)|dx=0$ even though $f(x)=1$ at one point.

Comment: I think functions that are zero a.e is not necessarily Riemann integrable ..... that is what I understood from here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2253528/metric-spaces-why-does-d-1f-g-int-01f-g-0-imply-f-g ....... right?

Comment: @Emptymind You have used the tags functional analysis and real analysis so I thought I could use Lebesgue integrals. I did not say that my function is Riemann integrable. Anyway, I have modified my example now.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to prove that $f=g$ if the metric $d(f,g)=0$. The proof in the image you attached uses the continuity property of the functions to show that if $f$ and $g$ differ at a point $x_0$ then they must differ at some finite "bump" around that point as well, such that the integral of the absolute value is not zero. The continuity of the functions is the essential content of this proof.

[image]

Your solution says the same thing, but it assumes the result about the integral being zero, so it's more of a statement assuming the answer.